# JODA LocalDate as QueryParam of Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I search Google a lot, but I find the answer very complicated and not compatible with JODA version 2.3.

I'm required to use LocalDate as QueryParam in my jersey service,
But LocalDate is not a supported by QueryParam as a valid data type.

Is there any other annotation or workaround to deal with LocalDate as a QueryParam?

```
@GET @Path("/available")
public List < AvailableClient > getAvailable(@QueryParam(value = "client") ClientDto client, @QueryParam(value = "from") LocalDate from, @QueryParam(value = "to") LocalDate to) {
    return client.get(from, to);
}
```

Here's the error:
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the date as a long value and create a LocalDate with this.

```
@GET @Path("/available")
public List < AvailableClient > getAvailable(@QueryParam(value = "client") ClientDto   client, @QueryParam(value = "from") long from, @QueryParam(value = "to") long to) {
   return client.get(new LocalDate(from), new LocalDate(to));
}
```

If you realy need to receive a LocalDate as a QueryParam, your need to create a [ParamConverter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverter.html).
This is not very simple, i prefer the long option because you can use a long with every date api in java.

[Here](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/11/inject-custom-java-types-via-jax-rs-parameter-annotations/) is a good example of a ParamConverter.

Comment: I am required to use the LocalDate as data type of parameter.

In other words I have to use the method signature of public List getAvailable(Client,LocalDate,LocalDate);

Comment: Why? how an api that is not made in java will call your api?

Comment: That was so complicated.

Comment: Alternatively, you can take a look at this blog regarding how to use ParamConverter
https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/jaxrs-convert-params